# Using Default Parameter in Functions with Two 'For Loops'

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array in descending order and ascending order. The program's output will print the unsorted array, the one sorted is descending order and the one sorted in ascending order. The thing is that I have to declare a single function and use default parameters. I cannot use function overloading. This is where my problem lies. I made two `for loops` one for the descending order and one for the ascending order. If I were function overloading it would be easy to print out each one, I could just have one function be `descendingOrder()` and the other one be `ascendingOrder()`. But since I am using a single function which is `selectionSort()`, I do not know how to make one `for loop` correspond to `selectionSort(arr, SIZE)` and the other to `selectionSort(arr, SIZE, 1)`. This might be an easy question to answer but I am just a beginner and I am really puzzled. Thanks for the help.

My code runs but it does not print my desired output. It prints the descending order twice instead of printing the descending order and then the ascending order.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 10;

void printArr(int* arr, int len){
    for(int i; i < len; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void selectionSort(int* arr, int n=0, int var = 0)
{
    int i, j, smallest;
    //loop for descending order
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        smallest = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j ++)
            if (arr[j] > arr[smallest])
                smallest=j;
        
        swap(&arr[smallest], &arr[i]);
    }
    //loop for ascending order
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        smallest = i;
        for(j = i+1; j<n; j++)
            if(arr[j] < arr[smallest])
                smallest=j;
        
        swap(&arr[smallest], &arr[i]);
    }
}
// Declare function "selectionSort" here.
// (using std::swap)

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE] = {5, 13, 6, 1, 32, 65, 87, 23, 14, 88};
    cout << "Before sort: " << endl;
    printArr(arr, SIZE);
    cout << "Sorted (descending order): " << endl;
    selectionSort(arr, SIZE);
    printArr(arr, 10);
    cout << "Sorted (ascending order): " << endl;
    selectionSort(arr, SIZE, 1);
    printArr(arr, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `// (using std::swap)` Was this comment left by your teacher? Have you already been introduced to function pointers, classes or references?

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, my instructor left that comment as a suggestion. And yes, I have been introduced to pointers and references but I am far from being an expert on them.

Comment: So, why didn't you followed it? ;)

Comment: @Bob__ I haven't been taught how to use ``std::swap`` yet so I rather not mess with it for now. If you can demonstrate how to use it in this example, it would be nice I guess. So I can at least see how it used but there is really no need. It was more of a suggestion rather than a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the only difference between your "functions" is the following line:

```
if (arr[j] > arr[smallest])
```

You can simply make this condition be dependent on `var` like this:

```
if (var ? arr[j] < arr[smallest] : arr[j] > arr[smallest])
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if ((var && arr[j] < arr[smallest]) || (!var && arr[j] > arr[smallest]))
```

and write just a single "function".

Comment: I would suggest using a regular if-statement for clarity since @Rivf may not have learned about ternaries yet.

Comment: @dave Ok, added an option without `?:`.

Comment: Thank you for adding the regular if-statements, as @dave said I have not learned about ternaries.

Answer (score 1):

> I made two for loops one for the descending order and one for the ascending order. [...] since I am using a single function which is `selectionSort()`, I do not know how to make one for loop correspond to `selectionSort(arr, SIZE)` and the other to `selectionSort(arr, SIZE, 1)`.

An "easy" way could be to use an `if`

```
if ( val == 0 ) {
//loop for descending order
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
else {
    //loop for ascending order
    for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
        // ...     
    }
}
```

But that's a lot of error prone code duplication.

A different approach, one that I think is understandable to a beginner which may have a limited knowledge of the language features (read: there are far better ways, but you'll learn them later) involves the use of a comparator function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 10;

void printArr(int* arr, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    //      ^^^^^                  Note the initialization.
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

// It returns 1 if a < b, -1 if b < a or 0 if a == b
int compare_int(int a, int b)
{
    return (a < b) - (b < a);
}

// Declare function "selectionSort" here.
// ^^^^^^^
void selectionSort( int* arr
                  , int n
                  , int var = -1 );

int main()
{
    int arr[SIZE] = {5, 13, 6, 1, 32, 65, 87, 23, 14, 88};
    cout << "Before sort: " << endl;
    printArr(arr, SIZE);
    cout << "Sorted (descending order): " << endl;
    selectionSort(arr, SIZE);
    printArr(arr, SIZE);
    cout << "Sorted (ascending order): " << endl;
    selectionSort(arr, SIZE, 1);
    printArr(arr, SIZE);
    return 0;
}

// (using std::swap)

void selectionSort( int* arr
                  , int n
                  , int var )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i ) {
        int smallest = i;
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j ) {
            if ( compare_int(arr[j], arr[smallest]) == var ) {
            //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
                smallest = j;
            }
        }   
        std::swap(arr[smallest], arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I tried implementing the function you wrote with ``std::swap`` and I am not getting the correct output.

Comment: @Rivf Sorry, a `{` went lost while editing. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ExzxhK) it works, could you please check?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot.